# How would I convert this code to Generics?

Tags: java, generics

I am in desperate need of help here. I am to migrate this existing code to generics and I've really hit a wall. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The existing code is an algorithm library and is accompanied by some classes with constructors for vehicles (i.e Bike.Java).

I've tried alot of different things but I just can't seem to figure it out. I'd love some insight.

```
public class Algo
{
  /**
   * Copies all objects from src to tgt, for which the predicate pred holds.
   *
   * @param src source list
   * @param tgt target list
   * @param pred unary predicate
   */
  static public
  void copyIf(List src, List tgt, UnaryPredicate pred)
  {
    for (Object obj : src)
    {
      if (pred.test(obj)) tgt.add(obj);
    }
  }

/**
   * Copies all objects from src to tgt that are greater than yardstick.
   *
   * @param src source
   * @param tgt target
   * @param yardstick determines if objects in src should be copied to tgt.
   */
  static public
  void copyIfGreaterThan(List src, List tgt, final Comparable yardstick)
  {
    copyIf(src, tgt, new UnaryPredicate() {
      public boolean test(Object o)
      {
        return yardstick.compareTo(o) < 0;
      }
    });
  }

  /**
   * Finds a maximum object in lst.
   *
   * @param lst a list containing non-null references
   * @return a maximum object in lst
   */
  static public
  Comparable findMax(List lst)
  {
    assert lst != null;

    Comparable max  = null;
    Iterator   iter = lst.iterator();

    // handle first element
    if (iter.hasNext())
      max = (Comparable) iter.next();

    // handle remaining elements
    while (iter.hasNext())
    {
      assert max != null;

      Comparable cand = (Comparable) iter.next();

      if (max.compareTo(cand) < 0)
        max = cand;
    }

    return max;
  }

  /**
   * Adds the smaller of lhs and rhs to dst.
   *
   * @param lhs left hand side object
   * @param rhs right hand side object
   * @param dst destination list
   */
  static public
  void storeMin(Comparable lhs, Comparable rhs, List dst)
  {
    Comparable min = lhs;

    if (min.compareTo(rhs) > 0) min = rhs;

    dst.add(min);
  }

  /**
   * swaps the elements at a and b in lst.
   *
   * @param lst a list
   * @param a first location in lst
   * @param b second location in lst
   */
  static private
  void swap(ArrayList objs, int a, int b)
  {
    Object tmp = objs.get(a);

    objs.set(a, objs.get(b));
    objs.set(b, tmp);
  }

  /**
   * Sorts the elements in lst.
   *
   * @param lst an array list containing non-null references
   */
  static public
  void selectionSort(ArrayList lst)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < lst.size(); ++i)
    {
      int        min = i;
      Comparable minobj = (Comparable) lst.get(min);

      for (int j = i+1; j < lst.size(); ++j)
      {
        if (minobj.compareTo(lst.get(j)) > 0)
        {
          min = j;
          minobj = (Comparable) lst.get(min);
        }
      }

      swap(lst, min, i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *I've tried alot of different things* like...

Comment: I have downvoted this question because you are asking us about a bug without showing us code.  Without concrete code, we can only guess what the problem might be, which is not useful to you or future readers.  If you can [edit] your question to show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem, this downvote may be retracted.

Comment: Start by enabling all compiler warnings.  Then pay attention to them, especially the ones about a “raw type.”

Answer (score -2):

Since Java 8 you could do it like that:

```
public static <T> List<T> copyIf(List<T> src, Predicate<T> predicate){
    return src.stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static <T> List<T> copyIfGreaterThan(List<T> src, Comparable<T> yardstick) {
    return copyIf(src, t -> (yardstick.compareTo(t) < 0));
}
```

For more infos about generics see:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

For more infos on streams see e.g. 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_streams.htm

Comment: Hey so That helped alot! I was able to figure that part out. I have a question though: We had to implement a tester for the generic code, but we were also to implement a tester for the original code (above) that had some examples of things that WOULDN'T work with the new generic code. Could you give me an example of what those things may be? Wouldn't it make sense that they all work? I hope that made sense.

Comment: a tester for the code above could be done with casting think, but i am not shure if i understand you correctly. Do you want some test code for your first example?